# Combine data from multiple objects into something readable by chartJS

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have some data like this (ignore that they all have the same date, they will normally have different dates):

```
[
    {
        "Raise Hand": 0,
        "Be Quiet": 1,
        "Ask For Help": 2,
        "Be Good": 3,
        "Comment": "four?",
        "date": "2022-03-05",
        "email": "me@example.com"
    },
    {
        "Raise Hand": 0,
        "Be Quiet": 1,
        "Ask For Help": 2,
        "Be Good": 3,
        "Comment": "four?",
        "date": "2022-03-05",
        "email": "parent.email@email.orggg"
    },
    {
        "Raise Hand": 0,
        "Be Quiet": 1,
        "Ask For Help": 2,
        "Be Good": 3,
        "Comment": "four?",
        "date": "2022-03-05",
        "email": "me@example.com"
    },
    {
        "Raise Hand": 0,
        "Be Quiet": 1,
        "Ask For Help": 1,
        "Be Good": 1,
        "Comment": "a",
        "date": "2022-03-05",
        "email": "parent.email@email.orggg"
    },
    {
        "Raise Hand": 0,
        "Be Quiet": 0,
        "Ask For Help": 0,
        "Be Good": 0,
        "Comment": "a",
        "date": "2022-03-05",
        "email": "parent.email@email.orggg"
    },
    {
        "Raise Hand": 2,
        "Be Quiet": 2,
        "Ask For Help": 2,
        "Be Good": 2,
        "Comment": "asd",
        "date": "2022-03-05",
        "email": "parent.email@email.orggg"
    },
    {
        "Raise Hand": 4,
        "Be Quiet": 4,
        "Ask For Help": 4,
        "Be Good": 4,
        "Comment": "asds",
        "date": "2022-03-05",
        "email": "parent.email@email.orggg"
    },
    {
        "Raise Hand": 1,
        "Be Quiet": 2,
        "Ask For Help": 1,
        "Be Good": 0,
        "Comment": "asdsd",
        "date": "2022-03-05",
        "email": "parent.email@email.orggg"
    },
    {
        "Raise Hand": 2,
        "Be Quiet": 1,
        "Ask For Help": 1,
        "Be Good": 3,
        "Comment": "asdsd",
        "date": "2022-03-05",
        "email": "parent.email@email.orggg"
    },
    {
        "Raise Hand": 3,
        "Be Quiet": 2,
        "Ask For Help": 1,
        "Be Good": 2,
        "Comment": "ads",
        "date": "2022-03-05",
        "email": "parent.email@email.orggg"
    },
    {
        "Raise Hand": 1,
        "Be Quiet": 2,
        "Ask For Help": 1,
        "Be Good": 1,
        "Comment": "asds",
        "date": "2022-03-05",
        "email": "parent.email@email.orggg"
    },
    {
        "Raise Hand": 3,
        "Be Quiet": 2,
        "Ask For Help": 1,
        "Be Good": 2,
        "Comment": "asds",
        "date": "2022-03-05",
        "email": "parent.email@email.orggg"
    }
]
```

And I need the data formatted into something like this with a new array for each 'challenge'. X would be the date and Y would be the value of that 'challenge' on that particular day:

```js
[{x:"2-22-22", y:2}, {x:"2-23-22", y:3}]
```

For example, it would have an array for 'Raise Hand', an array for 'Be Quiet', etc. but also be dynamic so I can add more 'challenges' or replace them later. I also don't need date, email, and anything containing 'comment' taken out.
Raise Hand:

```js
[{x:"2-22-22", y:0},{x:"2-23-22", y:0},{x:"2-24-22", y:1}, ect]
```

I've spent a few hours working on this and this is how far I've gotten:

```js
function formatData() {
        let labels = []
        let keys = []
        //* Get keys
        for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            for(let j = 0; j < Object.keys(data[i]).length; j++) {
                if(keys.indexOf(Object.keys(data[i])[j]) == -1) {
                    keys.push(Object.keys(data[i])[j])
                } 
            }
        }
        keys = reduceKeys(keys)
        
        let totalData = {}
        //* Get data for each key
        for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            for(let j = 0; j < keys.length; j++) {
                //* If data[i] DOES NOT have keys[j] then do this
                if(Object.keys(data[i]).indexOf(keys[j]) != -1) {
                    //* Make new key with array if it does not exist
                    if(Object.keys(totalData).indexOf(keys[j]) == -1) {
                        totalData[keys[j]] = []
                    }
                    totalData[keys[j]].push(data[i][keys[j]])
                } else {
                    //* Make new key with array if it does not exist
                    if(Object.keys(totalData).indexOf(keys[j]) == -1) {
                        totalData[keys[j]] = []
                    }
                    //* If the key does not exist for that entry the put 0
                    totalData[keys[j]].push(0)
                }
                if(data[i].date == null || data[i].date == undefined) {
                    labels.push("Error: No date")
                } else {
                    labels.push(data[i].date)
                }
            }
        }
        console.log(totalData)
        console.log(labels)
        let outputData = []
        for(let i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
            let tempArr = []
            for(let j = 0; j < Object.keys(totalData).length; j++) {
                // Object.keys(totalData)
                let length = totalData[Object.keys(totalData)[j]].length
                for(let k = 0; i < )
            }
        }
    }

    //* remove comments, date, and email
    function reduceKeys(keyArr) {
        let output = []
        for(let i = 0; i < keyArr.length; i++) {
            let key = keyArr[i]
            if(key.toLowerCase().includes("comment") || key.toLowerCase().includes("date") || key.toLowerCase().includes("email")) continue
            output.push(key)
        }
        return output
    }
```

For more info on how I need the data formatted please look at this [ChartJS docs page](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/data-structures.html)

Comment: What is the `y` property in the desired output meant to represent?

Comment: Sorry, I should've explained that. X would be the date and Y would be the value of that 'challenge' on that particular day

Comment: So each object in the input array will result in an object for *each* key on that day, is that right? Eg if the input was only `[{
        "Raise Hand": 0,
        "Be Quiet": 1,
        "Ask For Help": 2,
        "Be Good": 3,
        "Comment": "four?",
        "date": "2022-03-05",
        "email": "me@example.com"
    }]` the output would be `[{x:"2-22-22", y:0},{x:"2-22-22", y:1},{x:"2-22-22", y:2},{x:"2-22-22", y:3}]`, one for each of those keys except Comment, date, and email, is that right?

Comment: If not, a concrete example of an input and exact desired output from it would help (without fudged or made up data)

Comment: No. The output would be a separate array for each key in the object excluding date, email, and comments. So for your input it would output 4 arrays containing one object. [{x:"2-22-22", y:0}] [{x:"2-22-22", y:1}] [{x:"2-22-22", y:2}] [{x:"2-22-22", y:3}]. Or probably an array of arrays of objects.

Comment: Example Data 1: https://pastebin.com/K9h0bme8 Example Data 2: https://pastebin.com/Lp7y3DGA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the simplest straightforward approach would be to have a single nested loop, where you iterate over all properties but `Comment`, `date`, and `email`, pushing to an array identified by the property being iterated over, and creating the array first if it doesn't exist - then take the `Object.values` of the resulting object of arrays at the end.

```js
const input = [
    {
        "Raise Hand": 0,
        "Be Quiet": 1,
        "Ask For Help": 2,
        "Be Good": 3,
        "Comment": "four?",
        "date": "2022-03-05",
        "email": "me@example.com"
    },
    {
        "Raise Hand": 0,
        "Be Quiet": 1,
        "Ask For Help": 2,
        "Be Good": 3,
        "Comment": "four?",
        "date": "2022-03-06",
        "email": "parent.email@email.orggg"
    },
];
const outputByExercise = {};
for (const item of input) {
  const { Comment, date, email, ...rest } = item;
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(rest)) {
    outputByExercise[key] ??= [];
    outputByExercise[key].push({ date, value });
  }
}
const output = Object.values(outputByExercise);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thank you I think this is what I need. I'm glad there are JS wizards out here able to get the output I was looking for in 10 minutes.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need parse manually. You can use ChartJs parser like

```
const data = [{x: 'Jan', "Raise Hand": 100, "Be Quiet": 50, "Ask For Help": 50}, {x: 'Feb',  "Raise Hand": 100, "Be Quiet": 50, "Ask For Help": 50}];
const cfg = {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Jan', 'Feb'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Rise hand',
            data: data,
            parsing: {
                yAxisKey: "Raise Hand"
            }
        }, {
            label: 'Be Quiet',
            data: data,
            parsing: {
                yAxisKey: "Be Quiet"
            }
        }, {
            label: 'Help',
            data: data,
            parsing: {
                yAxisKey: "Ask For Help"
            }
        }]
    },
};
```

I took example from the link you shared :)

Comment: The problem with this is I need a new chart for each 'challenge' and your example is a new chart for each day

Comment: Do you have any example chart?

Comment: The problem is solved but thank you for trying